# Writing multithreaded video and audio packets with FFmpeg

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, audio, ffmpeg

I couldn't find any information on the way `av_interleaved_write_frame` deals with video and audio packets.

I have multiple audio and video packets coming from 2 threads. Each thread calls a `write_video_frame` or `write_audio_frame`, locks a mutex, initialize an AVPacket and writes data to an .avi file.

Initialization of AVCodecContext and AVFOrmatContext is ok.

**-- Edit 1 --**

Audio and video are coming from an external source (microphone and camera) and are captured as raw data without any compression (even for video). 
I use h264 to encode video and no compression for Audio (PCM).

Audio captured is: 16bits, 44100khz, stereo

Video captured is 25FPS

**Question:**

1) Is it a problem if I write multiple video packets at once (let's say 25 packets/sec) and just one audio packet/sec.

***Answer: Apparently not, the function `av_interleaved_write_frame` should be able to manage that kind of data as soon as pts and dts is well managed***

This means I call `av_interleaved_write_frame` 25 times for video writing and just 1 for audio writing per second. Could this be a problem ? If it is how can I deal with this scenario ?

2) How can I manage pts and dts in this case ? It seems to be a problem in my application since I cannot correctly render the .avi file. Can I use real time stamps for both video and audio ?

***Answer: The best thing to do here is to use the timestamp given when capturing audio / video as pts and dts for this kind of application. So these are not exactly real time stamps (from wall clock) but media capture timestamps.***

Thank you for your precious advices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`av_interleaved_write_frame` writes otput packets in such way so they are properly interleaved (maybe queueing them internally). "Properly interleaved" depends on a container format but usually it means that DTS stamps of the packets in output file are monotonically increasing.

`av_interleaved_write_frame`, like most FFmpeg APIs, shouldn't be ever called simultaneously by two threads with same AVFormatContext. I assume you make sure of that with a mutex. If you do then it doesn't matter whether it is multithreaded application or now.

> Is it a problem if I write multiple video packets at once (let's say 25 packets/sec) and just one audio packet/sec

It is not a problem in general but most audio codecs can't output 1 second long audio packets. Which codec do you use?

> How can I manage pts and dts in this case? Can I use real time stamps for both video and audio ?

Same way as you would in single-threaded application. Dts usually are generated by codecs from pts. Pts usually comes from a capture device/decoder together with the corresponding audio/video data.

Real time stamps *might* be ok to use but it really depends on how and when you are acquiring them. Please elaborate on what exactly you are trying to do. Where is audio/video data coming from?

Comment: I added some information about both video and audio source. I do use mutexes to be thread safe and this work nice.As mentionned I'm not using any compression for audio and I'm capturing 1 second packets which mean 176400 bytes of data per second. Is that too much data to use with `av_interleaved_write_frame` ? If so, how should I manage this situation ?

Comment: I see. `av_interleaved_write_frame` in general can deal with this kind of packets; maybe avi format/muxer has some limitations in this area? Probably not though. Regarding timestamps - if you are capturing A/V using e.g. DirectShow then it provides you with timestamps and you should use them as pts source; just make sure they have same reference time (i.e. samples captured in same moment will have same time stamps). Using wallclock time might be an issue because it can cause a lot of jitter in timestamps unless it is compensated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this give me some ideas since I have timestamps when capturing which I can use for pts / dts. Another question though when I'm capturing audio as raw data, can I directly use `av_interleaved_write_frame` or do I have to encode the data with PCM_S16LE and then write the data ?

Comment: You don't have to use a codec but you need to set up muxer's stream and each AVPacket correctly. Emulating codec like pcm16le on little-endian machine is almost trivial.